# iOS NSCoding NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nscoding

I have `.h` and `.m` to implement `NSCoding`, but the `mutableArray` object count always be 0...

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Favorite : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSMutableArray *myArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "Favorite.h"

@implementation Favorite
- (void)dealloc {
    [myArray release];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:myArray];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    myArray = [[decoder decodeObject] retain];
    return self;
}
@end
```

I'll use this class like

```
Favorite *fav = [[Favorite alloc] init];
fav.myArray = self.anotherArray;
[fav release];
```

Is it correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate the `NSMutableArray` like this ,

```
myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

happy coding

Comment: I add the init function to Favorite.m still get myArray count 0, please help me.
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.myArray = array;
        [array release];
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: [encoder encodeObject: myArray forKey:@"myArray"]; then while decoding myArray  = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myArray "];...try this

Comment: Thank you very much!! I've written a sample, and it's work!! I'll check my code to find why the array count always be 0, thanks again : )